# vb.net how to make comma to file size

Tags: vb.net

I'm making an updater, so I'm showing to users actual filesize / downloaded file size. In the below codes, shows me like that: "3MB / 3MB". I'm making that with mb, but I want to make it like that: "3,30MB / 2,20MB".

How can I do that? Is there example?

```
 Dim Totalbytes As Long = e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024
 Dim Bytes As Long = e.BytesReceived / 1024
 Dim Totalmbytes As Long = Totalbytes / 1024
 Dim Mbytes As Long = Bytes / 1024

 sbytes = Bytes.ToString
 Patch_Speed.Text = "Hız: " & speed.ToString & " KB/s"
 Patch_DownloadStatus.Text = "İndirilen: " & Mbytes.ToString & " Mb / " & Totalmbytes.ToString & " Mb"
```

Comment: start by turning on `Option Strict`, then consider that a `Long` does not have decimals, so your calculations are discarding the fractions.  go from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a floating point type like `Double` or `Decimal` instead of `Long`:

```
Dim Mbytes As Double = Bytes / 1024
```

If you set `Option Strict` to `On` your code does not even compile since `/` returns double.

Apart from that, if you always want to have two decimal places as in `3,30MB` you can use:

```
Mbytes.ToString("#.#0") & "MB";
```

or with `String.Format`:

```
String.Format("{0:#.#0}MB", Mbytes);
```

Comment: Is there a good example? I converted long to double but now shows me weird values...

Comment: @Liveth: i have showed an example `Dim Mbytes As Double = Bytes / 1024`. The division already returns a `Double`. So your assignment to the `Long` variable is incorrect and only compiles because you have set `Option Strict` to `Off`. Then the compiler tries to help you by converting that double to `Long` which truncates all decimal places. Just leave it as double.